# How to use JavaScript method hasFocus() not on whole document but on element inside document?

Tags: javascript, focus, onfocus

The definition on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_hasfocus.asp) says that it can be done, but nowhere it's shown how.
Snippet:

```
if (document.getElementById(atr).hasFocus())
{
  console.log("focused");
}
else
{
  console.log("not focused");
}
```

Comment: The w3 docs are saying that `document.hasFocus()` returns true if any element on the page is focused, not that you can just call `hasFocus` on any element. Some of the answers have a way you can check that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel this is down to a misreading of the document. The doc says:

> The hasFocus() method returns a Boolean value indicating whether the document (or any element inside the document) has focus.

It is not saying that *you* can check either the document, or any element you want, instead it is saying it will check if the document *or any element inside the document* has focus

---

To propose a method with similiar functionality you can simply compare `document.activeElement` with your chosen element

```js
// Get Element
let testElement = document.getElementById('container');

// Check against .activeElement
let isFocused = (document.activeElement === dummyEl);
```

Answer (score 1):

To do the hasFocus method on an element, you first need to select it like so `document.getElementById(elementId)` and then put that in a variable to make it easier such as `let testElement = document.getElementById(elementId)` and then test this element with the hasFocus method as seen **below**

```js
if(document.activeElement == testElement){
//DO something...
}
```

Comment: Yeah... ofc, but I have a error message: TypeError: "document.getElementById(...).hasFocus is not a function"